# Spreadsheet(GAS)での複数範囲選択の取得

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Spreadsheets Add-on (Google Apps Script)で

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = ss.getActiveRange();
var values = range.getValues();
```

としたとき、選択範囲がCtrlやCommandで画像のように複数に渡って選択されていた場合に、

```
value: [[a11,b11,c11],[a12,b12,c12],[a13,b13,c13],[a14,b14,c14]]
```

が返される(最後に選択した部分のみのvaluesが返ってくる)

最初に選択した範囲もrangeとして取得したいが何か方法はないでしょうか。

[image: 複数範囲選択]

Answer (score 1):

`getActiveRange()` で 複数範囲を Ctrl で選択した場合、一部のセルしか取得できません。
要望も挙がっているようですが、現時点では未対応のようです。

Add support to allow use and manipulate disjoint Ranges
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761866